# Need to Print Value of a Variable using Paste in R

Tags: r, append

I am trying to create a data frame of various error messages based on Data to be cross checked between two dataframes and storing the message in a vector in an iterative manner . I am using the following snippet for this purpose :

```
> for(j in 1:nrow(MySQL_Data)){   date_mysql=
> paste("MySQL_Data[",j,",1]")   date_red= paste("RED_Data[",j,",1]")  
> body= c() if(!date_mysql == date_red) {
>     body<- append(body,paste("'There is data missing for date",date_mysql,"in",table2))   }else {
>       NULL }}
```

My `table2` variable prints as MYSQL_Data[2,1] instead of the actual value of the variable which is a date 
Following is the Output :

```
"'There is data missing for date MySQL_Data[ 2 ,1] in Dream11_UserRegistration"
```

Can someone help me with the error that I am committing here..

Thanks in Advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your use of `paste` in the definitions of `data_mysql` and `data_red` makes no sense. I’m assuming that what you actually want is this:

```
data_mysql = MySQL_Data[j, 1]
data_red = RED_Data[j, i]
```

Furthermore, you’re resetting `body` in every loop iteration so it will only ever hold a single element.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Konrad this was really helpful